# WPF Button style won't apply to second button

Tags: wpf, wpf-style

I have two buttons that use a static common style:

```
<Button x:Name="BtnCreate" Height="22" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource Style.Button.Trash}"/>
<Button x:Name="aefae" Height="22" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource Style.Button.Trash}"/>
```

The style is very basic:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="Style.Button.Trash" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Image Source="{StaticResource Image.Trash}" Width="22" Height="22"/>
            <Label Content="Save" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="26" />
        </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The style applies to the first button and display both the image an the text however the second button does not display anything except a grey button.

Why does the second button not use the static style?

Comment: Is the resource image set shared? (x:Shared="false")

Comment: Are those buttons as shown here one under other or you have them in different files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In WPF, can I share the same image resource between 2 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110068/in-wpf-can-i-share-the-same-image-resource-between-2-buttons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're trying to add the same `Content` to two `Button`s, elements (present in `Style`) cannot be added to two different Logical Parents. To avoid this, you can set `x:Shared="False"` to your style.